# Socket.io and Gcloud page refresh reconnects first

Tags: socket.io, gcloud

When I'm running the app locally and I refresh the page, it shows that the user disconnects first then reconnects. But on gcloud, the user reconnects first and then disconnects after about 10 seconds. Help pls :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched to digitalocean and problem was fixed xD.
Thnx every1!!